# Docker build image cannot create temp file /etc/ permission denied

Tags: изображения, docker, build, dockerfile

Всем привет! Во время сборки docker образа появляется ошибка
[image: Can't create file /etc permission denied]

Ошибка возникает регулярно, лечится перезагрузкой службы docker

```
systemctl restart docker
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine3.12

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 COLUMNS=200 TZ='Asia/Almaty'

RUN mkdir /esb
ADD ./esb/requirements.txt /esb
ADD ./docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh

RUN sed -i 's/dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/mirror.neolabs.kz/g' /etc/apk/repositories \
    && apk add \
           tzdata \
           python3 \
           py3-pip \
    && ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Almaty /etc/localtime \
    && echo "Asia/Almaty" > /etc/timezone \
    && apk add --update --no-cache \
           bash \
           libffi-dev \
           libc-dev \
           linux-headers \
           python3-dev \
           zlib-dev \
           gcc \
           g++ \
           curl-dev \
           libressl-dev \
           mariadb-dev \
    && mkdir -p /esb \
    && pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install -U -r /esb/requirements.txt \
    && addgroup -S gunicorn \
    && adduser -D -S -G gunicorn gunicorn \
    && chown -R gunicorn:gunicorn /esb

COPY ./esb /esb

WORKDIR /esb
USER user
CMD ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Это к сожалению не мой вывод, поэтому не могу сделать в текстовом виде(